# How to Add multi values from checkbox into procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have 4 checkbox, if checkbox was checked or unchecked it will save to a table in sql database by parameter on Procedure, here is my code, but it not do any thing. And I want to make checkbox changed even,user checked or checked on checkbox, it will save 0 or 1 value on database automatically.If I make it on every checkbox it will ok but how to make checkbox checked changed in a loop? Can you help me? thank you very much, I am a learner

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SopProcess", con);//đưa câu lệnh sql đi thực thi  
cmd.CommandText = "SopProcess";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
bool[] checkstatus = { cb1.Checked, cb5.Checked, cb9.Checked, cb13.Checked };
string[] checkid = { cb1.Text, cb5.Text, cb9.Text, cb13.Text };
int j = checkid.Length;
int f = checkstatus.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckID", checkid[i]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusClick", check[i]);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

And here is my Procedure

```
  Alter Proc SopProcess(@CheckID nvarchar(50),@StatusClick int)
  As
  Begin

  Create Table #Checkbox(checkboxid nvarchar(50),Checkstatus int)
  Declare @insert int = 'insert into   #Checkbox(checkboxid,Checkstatus)values('+@CheckID+','+@StatusClick+')'


 IF(@insert>0)
 Update StoreStatus Set Checkstatus = 1 Where Checkid = '"+@CheckID+"'
 Else
 Update StoreStatus Set Checkstatus = 0 Where Checkid = '"+@checkID+"'
 Select * From StoreStatus

 End
```

My Procedure on top, but as I run code c# it show error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'insert into #Checkbox(checkboxid,Checkstatus)values(,' to data type int.". I changed to int all I can't repair too.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: sorry..my question is how to save multi checkbox valuve when user checked  or uncheck on checkbox into database by using parameter on Procedure

Answer (score 1):

**Hey Buddy**,

Please describe more details about your question.
Based on your code posted. I can only give you this answer.

**UPDATED!**

```
bool[] checkstatus = { cb1.Checked, cb5.Checked, cb9.Checked, cb13.Checked };
string[] checkid = { cb1.Text, cb5.Text, cb9.Text, cb13.Text };

int j = checkid.Length; //this variable indicates the length of your array
int f = checkstatus.Length; //this variable indicates the length of you array

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "SopProcess";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CheckID", checkstatus[i]); //this should be the value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StatusClick", checkid[i]); // this should be the value
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

As you can see it, you need to put the Initialization of your SqlCommand instance inside the loop.
This will provide your stored procedure a new set of values every time it loops.

Check this one if this solve your problem.

Comment: No any body else help me ?

Comment: before you save, can check the value of your checkstatus  array. if those checkboxes has some value.  you may also post your updated code

Comment: Where your update code ? can you show me your code repair.

Comment: check the code i have posted, i updated it already. are your trying to save the changes of checkbox when clicked or on change. post the layout of your problem

Comment: Thank you OzLa, I see it now.

Comment: Now, it show error "Could not find store procedure" during the name procedure exactly, i don't know why

Comment: have you created your stored procedure? Kindy check the updated code.

Comment: OzLa,please help me see on my Procedure, in line Create table temporary, may be it incorrect, it show error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'insert into #Checkbox(checkboxid,Checkstatus)values(,' to data type int."

Comment: Try checking the value of checkboxid,Checkstatus before saving it. Myabe it has an empty value.. Add if the question posted on top.. please vote if it fixed your question.. thank you

Comment: you may email me if you have some problems in c#.. thanks.. ozlagame@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details.What I can understand from the post that you need to update db when you check or uncheck the checkbox.

In above case  you just need to write server-side event and bind it. So whenever you click on any of the checkbox it will fire the event and update

```
private void ChkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {

            }
        }

}
```

Now you have access to all your checkbox and depending on Id and check and unckeck value you can do use your existing logic. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I done it in the same is ok.But i want to it in to a loop and when i checked or uncheck on checkbox it will auto send to Store Procedure 2 values .And it will update value into a table in database.

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn  I have updated the code check and let us know if it helps